# Pool not a constructor when trying to connect using @Keyv/Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get this code to work, however, when I run it, I get to the end of the process, however, I then get the error 'Pool is not a Constructor'. How does one solve this?

```js
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const logsdb = new Keyv(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { table: 'modlogs' });

module.exports = class modlogs extends Command {
 constructor(client) {
  super(client, {
   name: 'modlog',
   group: 'moderation',
   memberName: 'modlogs',
   description: 'Used to set the mod-log of the server.',
   clientPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
   userPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
   args: [
    {
     key: 'logs',
     prompt:
      'Which channel do you want to set as the mod-log? (Without the `#`)',
     type: 'string',
    },
   ],
   guildOnly: true,
  });
 }
 async run(message, { logs }) {
  await logsdb
   .set(message.guild.id, logs)
   .then(message.channel.send(`Successfully set mod log to \`${logs}\``));
 }
};
```

Error Log:

```
2020-09-14T19:42:32.883176+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Pool is not a constructor

2020-09-14T19:42:32.883185+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/@keyv/postgres/src/index.js:15:18

2020-09-14T19:42:32.883224+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 79)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole error log?

Comment: Well, it seems I found the problem. The bot can't connect to the Database server, because the db console shows 0 connections. I think that's why it's not working.